# Project versions

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Do you guys know a good way to maintain projects versions.

Currently I'm just zipping the entire folder of my website each time I decide that it is new version and call it for ex. 2.0.1

Is there a better way to maintain project versions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

or you can use Git its free & extremely fast , you can Git Extensions , download it for extensions manager

Comment: +1 - just started using Git with Git extensions and Github and have to say that I'm impressed so far.

Answer (score 2):

Team Foundation Server is prohibitively expensive, and I wouldn't consider Visual Source Safe at all.  Alternatives are:

1. Subversion - http://subversion.tigris.org/
2. Git - http://git-scm.com/
3. Mercurial - https://www.mercurial-scm.org

http://martinfowler.com/bliki/VersionControlTools.html is a nice article which may help you decide.

Comment: Team Foundation Server is a lot cheaper than some other competitive ALM solutions. And is zero marginal cost if developers have VS + MSDN already (i.e. you've already paid for it).

Comment: To be honest, even if it was free, I wouldn't choose TFS over the alternatives provided.  The disadvantage of an ALM solution is that it increases vendor lock-in.  For example, I wouldn't choose another CI tool over TeamCity, so what advantages would TFS provide me?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking into [Team Foundation Server](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/team-foundation-server) if you have the budget.  If not, something like [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) integrates nicely with Visual Studio and works really well.  [Git](http://git-scm.com/) is also very good.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a source control software like `Visual Source Safe` or `Team Foundation Server`?

They support File and Project versioning.

Comment: I should hope that they support file and project versioning!

Comment: I would avoid Visual Source Safe unless you are *already* using it (in which case look at using something better: it is better than no VCS, but that's it). Free tools (Subversion, GIT, Mecurial, ...) are all superior to VSS for VCS. Tools like TFS do far more than just VCS.